# Paypal subscription payment Error Message 3005

Tags: php, paypal

**i was trying paypal recurring payment and use this form**

form action="" name="_xclick-subscriptions" method="post">

When login for payment in paypal the error message occurs

**Sorry - your last action could not be completed**

If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.

If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.

If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left-hand corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.

For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

**Message 3005**

Why each time this error occurs

Comment: please share the complete code to check

Comment: We got this issue with our customers for payments more than 1000 USD. Don't know why, we will check this. When we set payment amount <= 1000 USD the error has gone.

Answer (score 4):

Paypal returns this message when your Paypal account's primary email address has not been verified.  To verify your Paypal Email account, please follow the following steps:

Log into your Paypal Account. You should be in the “Overview” tab.

Click on your Email address

Click on your Email address, under “Business account overview”, you will be taken to a Web page listing your Paypal Email addresses.

Select your Primary email address.

Click on the “Confirm” button.

Follow the rest of the Paypal instructions.

Comment: If someone is using Paypal's sandbox, there must be two accounts, one for merchant (seller) and another for a buyer. These test e-mails should be registered in Sandbox https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts# and merchant email address must be set in your webapp (i.e. Woocomerce)

Comment: Are you referring to the account being used to Pay or the recipients account? If you are referrring to the account being used to pay - I am getting this error while using the live paypal gateway and using a verified paypal account to attempt payment

Comment: I got this error when used PayPal sandbox. I had merchant account email contained '+' sign (like me+merchant@gmail.com). I just recreated merchant account without '+' sign and it works.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Junior M's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66708/junior-m) comment, another reason would be the incorrect email address setup in the web app. For testing you must have 3 email addresses (1 real and 2 fakes will work).

1. Real Email Address - To register on Paypal's developer site
2. 1st Fake email address - To be registered as Seller after logging into Paypal's developer site.
3. 2nd Fake email address - To be registered as Buyer after logging into Paypal's developer site.

You must need to set email address used in step #2 above in your webapp. To make payments, you need to use email address used in Step #3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two other causes to this error when using the sandbox:

- this error also arises when you are simultaneously logged in with your real account;
- and when you have the paypal s_sess cookie set (cookies should therefore be deleted between tests).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was sending the country name instead of the country code in a SetPaymentOptions request. The request came back with a 200 OK response, but then the checkout failed with a 3005 error.