# I am getting paypal error after login in sandbox during payment

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting given bellow error in paypal after login in sandbox.

We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.

For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

Message 3005

[image]

Comment: Try and verify the email address for the paypal account. I think that should be the cause for this error. Refer to this link on how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051819/paypal-subscription-payment-error-message-3005

Comment: I have tried the given above solution but i am getting still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal sandbox site have often difficulties. Wait a few hours and try again.

Comment: I am waiting from yesterday. I am getting this error yesterday onward.